# Identify areas within a shape/polygon with Vision / ML

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision

Given a shape, in the format of a binary image, I would like to detect and subdivide it to new areas. Below is an attached example of such a shape and the expected outcome where each new area is represented with a different color. I would possibly also like to classify the areas with categories.

Note that the shapes can also be highly irregular and different to the example below.

[image]
[image]

I tried some basic image manipulation methods with the scikit-image, but it was hard to get something to work on many different types of shapes.

Suppose I would try ML/DL instead and build up a dataset with different shapes and their expected outcomes. Is there a known solution/algorithm to this problem?

I looked at instance segmentation, but all the examples I can find are performed on real world images, and not binary images with a single fully connected shape. Would it be applicable to this problem anyway?

I have some experience with machine learning, but not much with image data or vision, so it would be most appreciated if someone could point me in the correct direction here.

Thanks.

Comment: "I tried some basic image manipulation methods with the scikit-image".  Like what?  there are lots of approaches that don't require machine learning, examples: [triangulation based](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/965887), [rectangular decomposition](http://library.utia.cas.cz/separaty/2012/ZOI/suk-rectangular%20decomposition%20of%20binary%20images.pdf), [hierarchical clustering](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gabriella-Sanniti-Di-Baja/publication/221364982_A_tool_for_decomposing_3D_discrete_objects/links/544e1fc70cf26dda088e4b3f/A-tool-for-decomposing-3D-discrete-objects.pdf) .